# Java drawing images outside of JPanel class

Tags: java, image, class, jpanel, paint

I have a WorldManager class that extends a JPanel and has:

`public void paint(Graphics g) {}`

What I would like to do is have separate classes, like a world class with its own paint method and be able to just call that classes paint method like so:

`public void paint(Graphics g) { world1.paint(); hero.paint(); }`

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`." [Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, there is nothing wrong with your approach.

1. As *trashgod* noted, you should overwrite the paintComponent method instead of the paint method.

   The reason for this is noted in the [article linked by *trashgod*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks): this way, the `paintBorder()` and `paintChildren()` method can do their painting of the border and the child components, and you are free to think only about the real content.
2. Your other paint methods should also take a Graphics parameter (or Graphics2D, if you need this and want to cast only once), and then be invoked.

Here is an example:

```
class WorldManager extends JPanel
{

    private World world1;
    private Person hero;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(); // paints the background, if opaque
         world.paint(g);
         hero.paint(g);
    }
}
```

So, what was your question, actually?

Comment: @Paulo
So I changed my paint method in my WorldManager to a paintComponent method and called super.paintComponent(g) and it works but can you explain to me as to why I must use a paintComponent instead of a regular paint method?

Comment: @Chris  Please do not forget to mark the question as 'answered/correct'.  This helps people who are searching for answers at a later date.